# Question Regarding Depositions

Tags: civil-procedure

Can a deposition be held without filing a lawsuit, going to trial, or absent any other court proceeding?

Comment: Law does not exist to adjudicate the truth of a fact *in isolation*.  That is the domain of philosophy, science, and perhaps other disciplines.

Comment: I think the edited question is unclear.  Do you mean, "*When* can a person be required to answer questions under oath without a court order?"

Comment: @feetwet, so, do I understand it correctly, a deposition can only be held once a lawsuit is filed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the US, going to trial would not be necessary, because all but a few depositions occur as part of the pretrial preparations. A lawsuit would be required, though, unless there are other applicable procedures, such as an administrative quasi-judicial proceeding or a Congressional hearing. There might be other ways to answer your question, but it's too hypothetical and nonspecific for me to offer more.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was an excellent and very helpful answer.